# Authentication android app using firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

My app keeps crashing after introducing registration details and clicking the 'register' button. The problem comes from those 2 functions somehow:

```
private fun registerUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: String, password: String) {
    val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            showToast("Account registered!")
            android.os.Handler().postDelayed({
                startActivity(Intent(this, CountDownActivity::class.java))
                overridePendingTransition(
                    R.animator.slide_in_left,
                    R.animator.slide_in_right
                )
                finish()
            }, 500)
        } else {
            val errorMessage = task.exception?.message
            if (errorMessage != null) {
                showToast("Registration error: $errorMessage")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
private fun checkIfEmailExists(email: String, username: String, password: String) {
    val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    auth.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email)
        .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                val signInMethods = task.result?.signInMethods
                if (signInMethods.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    registerUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                } else {
                    showToast("Email is already registered!")
                }
            } else {
                val errorMessage = task.exception?.message

                if (errorMessage != null) {
                    showToast("Registration error: $errorMessage")
                }
            }
        }
}
```

i have tried to comment each function, but the app was still crashing with just one of them being called.

Error logcat: PROCESS ENDED (7400)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.guesstheflag. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

Comment: When an app crashes, it writes an error message and stack trace to its logcat. Please find those, and add them to your question by clicking the `edit` link under it. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Comment: please share error logs so we can identify the issue and answer accordingly